# Is it possible that we can use “+” to add two vectors in polar form?

Tags: vector

For example, $a=(2,\pi/4)$, $b=(3,\pi/3)$, if we want to get the result of $a+b$, using `+` operator will not do, because mathematica will ignore the polar form, and regard `a` and `b` two two-dimension vectors in Cartesian coordinates. Polar vectors are used in phasor diagram.

Comment: So, create a special object, call it `Phasor[r, θ]`, and then define a way to add two `Phasor[]` objects: `Phasor /: Phasor[r1_, θ1_] + Phasor[r2_, θ2_] := (* stuff *)`… `Abs[]` and `Arg[]` will be useful, of course.

Comment: `Norm[]` and `Abs[]` are equivalent for complex number argument.

Comment: Oh yes...so I guess my problem has been solved.Thanks:D

Comment: Sean, if you made it work go ahead and post the solution as an answer.  (Otherwise the question will keep popping up as unanswered)

Comment: how to ......@george2079

Comment: @SeanPatrick using the form here below and clicking the button that says "post your answer". It would be great if you did that.

Comment: @Pickett  think I did it，any suggestion for my first answer in stackexchange?:D

Comment: There are a couple of things that would improve the post. 1) Post your code as code, not as an image. You can see in other posts how they format answers. 2) When you do this greek letters are going to be replaced by codes such as `\[rho]`. In order to convert these back to greek letters you can use [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/731) tool. 3) You can write it as a reusable function that people can copy into their own projects, using Guess who it is' `Phasor` definition above. 4) "c" in "change" should be capitalized. I already gave you my vote though.

Comment: @Pickett After my final exams I'll improve my answer soon....Asking a question is really much easier than answering one. I have a question:are we encouraged to post an answer to our own question? It seem to me most people comment on questions instead of answering them....

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.  Maybe it is just coincidence.... do I need to attribute to you?

Comment: It's entirely your call, but proper attributions are always appreciated.

Comment: @SeanPatrick Yes, if you can answer your own question then you are encouraged to do so because we don't like to leave questions unanswered and the answer might help someone in the future. It is also very discouraged to answer questions with comments, for this reason, but sometimes it happens. There is a discussion about this [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/posting-answers-in-comments).

Comment: I've post a new answer,I  don't know if I am doing better than last time,and I 'm not sure if I attribute to you properly....Actually I have two new questions: 1)" /:" defines only the operating between two Phasors,what if we need to add more than two? 2)if I want to have a format for the final answer,how to?@Guesswhoitis.

Comment: `AnglePath` might interest you.

Comment: @ChipHurst The difference between phasor addition and `AnglePath` is that the angles there are relative rotations, which isn't the same as complex addition.

Comment: This should not be this complicated...
There should a built in function for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Phasor /: Phasor[p1_, r1_] + Phasor[p2_, r2_] := p1E^(I r1) + p2E^(I r2)
Infix[{Abs[Phasor[3, Pi/3] + Phasor[3, Pi/6]], Arg[Phasor[3, Pi/3] + Phasor[3,Pi/6]]}, ","]`

---

Two lines of code is really enough to solve problem. Thanks for J. M.

Comment: …well, what you did is in fact what you're supposed to replace `(* stuff *)` with in my very first comment. :)

Comment: You can use `Module[]` to encapsulate your procedure…

Comment: Can you do an example for me? I have trouble understanding Module although Mathematica already gave some examples.This almost drives me crazy!！I’ve been working on this problem and also been modling Foucault's pendulum using mathematica for hours and  It's 3:40 am now!!I'have to go to sleep and I'll check news of this problem tomorrow .

Answer (score 5):

Here is a definition that works for arbitrary number of phasors:

```
ClearAll[phasor]

phasor /: Plus[p : _phasor ..] := 
 phasor @@ 
  ToPolarCoordinates@
   Total[{p} /. phasor -> (FromPolarCoordinates[{##}] &)]
```

Example:

```
phasor[1, Pi] + phasor[2, Pi/4] + phasor[3, Pi/3]
```

> $$\text{phasor}\left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{2}+\frac{3
>    \sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2},\tan
>    ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+\frac{3
>    \sqrt{3}}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

It uses the new functions (in version 10.1) [`FromPolarCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromPolarCoordinates.html) and [`ToPolarCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToPolarCoordinates.html).

To make it work with arbitrary number of phasors, I use a named pattern `p` with [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html), which collects all phasors appearing in a sum. They are then converted to Cartesian coordinates, added with `Total`, and converted back to phasor form (the last step could be omitted if you want the output to be in Cartesian coordinates).

Comment: I am still in version 10.so When I search  Wolfram  Documentation I didn't get much help.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: There is a function in version 10 called CoordinateTransformData perhaps this would help a bit,too.